# Map a Voltage range into another range

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, batteries, analog, adc

I'm making a battery voltage meter with a Wemos D1 Mini. The Analog input has a Vref of 3.2v. The battery that i will measure is a Lithio one of 72v, minimal 68V to max 84V, the Analog Input of the Wemos give to me (3.2v / 1024) of precision and i need more precision because with a resistor divisor i have a range from 0-90v but i will not use 0-60v, so my question is if with a OpAmp (i have a LM324) and some resistors i can map 60v-90v to 0v-30v and then use resistor divisor to down to 0-3.2v and get more precision with the ADC. The resolution that i want get is aprox 3mV-5mV

**Update**

I was used the document "Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds" with this values:
[image: Excel with values]

And used proteus to simulate the circuit of positive m and negative b

[image]

Like you see Vref' not is same (even closed) to calc and Vout is outside 3.1v range of calc... what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale and shift voltage signal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304116/how-to-scale-and-shift-voltage-signal)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124402/discussion-on-question-by-luis-felipe-dominguez-vega-map-a-voltage-range-into-an).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage conversion could be implemented like this:

[image]

To obtain:

[image]

Vref can be generated using precision adjustable reference (e. g. tl431) and R2 can be a trimpot. If you have specific requirements regarding the opamp power rails, reaching 0V could require some changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response...

Comment: the only problem is high current drawn from the battery. I have same problem and I do not to draw more than 70nA from the battery. Any idea?

Comment: @0___________ how much mA draw from battery??

Comment: @vangelo Why 13.6v for Vref?? can be 12v??

Comment: @LuisFelipeDominguezVega To change the original range to the (initially) desired one we have: (84 - 68) / 3.2 = 5. So the minimum voltage will be 68 / 5 = 13.6, which needs to be subtracted. The maximum current required from the battery is: 84/(47000+5222) = 1,609 mA.

Comment: @vangelo What simulation are you using? proteus don't get that values.

Comment: @LuisFelipeDominguezVega LTSpice: https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html